# JavaScript TimeStamp into MilliSeconds

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

I have a timestamp that looks like 09-MAR-11 04.52.43.246000000 AM.

I'm trying to convert this to a time format into MilliSeconds , Could anybody please let me know as how to achieve this ?? ( I Should do this inside JavaScript Only )

Please advice . Thanks .

Answer (score 10):

`parse()`: Returns the number of milliseconds since midnight 1 January 1970 for a given date and time string passed to it.

```
var milliSeconds = Date.parse('09-MAR-11 04:52:43:246000000 AM');
```

In your datestring please change the hour/min/etc separator to `:` instead of `.`, so JS can recognize correctly the date.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/UTfaB/)

[Javascript Date Functions](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm)

Comment: In IE 7 am getting a script error object doesn't support this property or method "var ms=d.parse('09-MAR-11 04.52.43.246000000 AM');"

Comment: I tried this way , as you mentioned , i got NAN 
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
function Call()
    {
var ms=Date.parse('09-MAR-11 04:52:43:246000000 AM');
alert(ms);
 }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="Call()">
  </body>
</html>

I got NAN . Please tell me if i am missing something here

Comment: I am getting NAN , Do i need to include any js file for this to work ?? Please advice , Thanks .

Comment: I have only tested this on Google Chrome. Please try out my jsFiddle Demo in your browser. The range of date formats that are recognized might differ between browsers.